# Запись в структуру в СИ

Tags: c, строки, файлы, структуры

помогите заполнить структуру привидённого вида 
Вот код , пытаюсь заполнить структуру. Необходимо заполнить структуру из файла.
Файл приведён к типу

```
1 : 20 наименование модели;
21 : 24 цена в долларах (целое число);
26 : 28 масса ноутбука в кг (число с десятичной точкой из четырех символов);
30 : 43 габаритные размеры ноутбука в дюймах (ВЫСОТАхДЛИНАхШИРИНА — три
числа с десятичной точкой (4 символа, включая точку, разделенные 'х');
44 : 47 частота процессора в МГц (целое число из трех символов);
49: 50 максимальный объем ОЗУ в мегабайтах (целое число из двух символов);
52 : 55 размер диагонали дисплея в дюймах (число с десятичной точкой из четырех
символов, включая точку);
57 размер видеопамяти в мегабайтах — целое число из одного символа;
59 : 67 разрешающая способность дисплея в пикселах (два целых числа, разделенные
'х');
69 : 70 частота регенерации дисплея в Гц (целое число из двух символов);
72 : 76 объем HDD в гигабайтах (число с десятичной точкой из пяти символов.
```

`введите сюда код`

```
struct NOTEBOOK
{
    char model[21]; // наименование
    struct size // габаритные размеры
    {
        float x;
        float y;
        float z;
    };
    float w; // вес
    int price; // цена
};

int main()
{
    struct NOTEBOOK data[20];
    FILE *from, *toto;
    from = fopen("note.txt", "r");
    toto = fopen("toto.bin", "wb+");
    char str[76];
    int i=0;
    int j=0;

    while ((str[i] = fgetc (from)) != EOF) {

        if (str[i] == '\n') {
            str[i] = '\0';

            i = 0;
            j++;
        }
        else {if ((i>=1)&&(i<=21)){data[j].model[i]=str[i];}i++;}
    }
    printf("%s",data[1].model);

}
```

Comment: В языке С запрещается объявлять один `struct` тип внутри другого без немедленного объявления поля. Ваш код не является корректным С кодом. Зачем вы запихнули объявление `struct size` внутрь объявления `struct NOTEBOOK`? Чего вы хотели этим добиться?

Comment: К сожалению данная структура приведена не мной ,а преподователем, добровольно я бы никогда не стал писать на С

Comment: Преподавателем или не преподавателем, именно такое объявление невозможно скомпилировать на С. Вы уверены, что вы точно воспроизвели код преподавателя?

Comment: Да, именно такая структура приведена в задании. Ничего не исправлено , я просто скопировал объявление структуры.

Comment: Продолжим про структуры :) некорректность получаеться при no named anonymous object (struct/union). В С99 выражается в варнинге `ISO C99 doesn't support unnamed structs/unions.` лечиться довольно просто, после последней закрывающей скобки придумываем имя: `} mystruct;` и потом покажите преподавателю :). Также собирать разумно с ключами '-Wall -pedantic' для GCC например. Имя size при этом убираем, будет анонимная но с именем поля :)

Comment: @NewView: Некорректность получается и в оригинальном коде, но другая. Clang и GCC хором: "declaration does not declare anything". А ваше "ISO C99 doesn't support unnamed structs/unions" - это вы уже чего-то зачем-то изменили в коде. Зачем?

Comment: @AnT, я к тому, что если автор поправит и уберет название структуры, то тут же возникнет следующая ошибка которую я и описал, вместе со способом как поправить :) надо было в ином порядке изложить, сперва про 'убрать название структуры size'

Comment: А где в этой структур поля из колонок 44..76?  Вообще, очень мало связи между структурой и описанием вводных данныз...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А сколько лет Вашему преподавателю? :-)  Такое впечатление, что он ставит задачу ввода данных с 80-ти колонных перфокарт! А структура данных очень похоже, взята из *COBOL*-а :-)

По сути, если не заморачиваться с подробной росписью ВСЕХ полей, то для тех полей, которые Вы уже перечислили в структуре, программа решается элементарными средствами форматирования в *fscanf*/  Как-то так:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct size // габаритные размеры
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
};

struct NOTEBOOK
{
    char model[21]; // наименование
    struct size ss;
    float w; // вес
    int price; // цена
};

#define FORMAT "%20s%4fx%4fx%4f%4f%4d"
#define VARLIST data[i].model,&data[i].ss.x,&data[i].ss.y,&data[i].ss.z,&data[i].w,&data[i].price

int main()
{
    struct NOTEBOOK data[20];
    FILE *from, *toto;
    from = fopen("note.txt", "r");
    toto = fopen("toto.bin", "wb+");
    int i=0, j;

    while (fscanf(from, FORMAT, VARLIST) != EOF) {
    // Здесь идёт запись в toto;
    // Печать введённой строки
    printf("%d) %s %4.1fx%4.1fx%4.1f %4.1f %4d\n", i,
        data[i].model, data[i].ss.x, data[i].ss.y, data[i].ss.z, data[i].w, data[i].price);
    i++;
    }
}
```

Тогда, если во входном файле *note.txt* набиты такие данные:

```
NameNameNameNameName11.1x22.2x33.3 444  55
namenamenamenamename66.6x77.7x88.8 999  00
```

То результат работы программы будет такой:

```
$ ./a.out 
0) NameNameNameNameName 11.1x22.2x33.3 444.0   55
1) namenamenamenamename 66.6x77.7x88.8 999.0    0
```

Comment: Преподователю 75 лет))